# Can't I Sleep without Windows.h?

Tags: c++

#include <windows.h> is needed for the sleep(int) function, but when I include it, I get errors. Do I need it in my code?

Comment: `Sleep` is a Windows API function, so you'll need to include `windows.h` somehow.

Comment: Are Windows API functions compatible with the console? Because regular lines of code that work fine without it all of the sudden cause errors. I am confused!

Comment: What are the extra errors? If you post them someone can probably help.

Comment: Because `Sleep()` is defined in `Windows h`, which you've commented out. If you're calling a basic WinAPI call, it makes no sense to comment out the header that defines those basic API calls. If you intentionally remove the definition, it's pretty senseless to question why the definition isn't there.

Comment: "Are Windows API functions compatible with the console?" - yes.

Comment: OK, after looking into it, there is only one line that gives errors.

Comment: Try adding `#undef max` before the `#include <windows.h>` line.

Comment: @JonathanPotter you mean to add `#undef max` **after** `#include` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes **after**.

Comment: What if you take away `dos.h`? Alternatively try calling `sleep` (lower case s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jonathan_Potter has said that `Sleep` is a part of `Windows API` & hence you need to include `windows.h` so I don't think you need to know any further why your code isn't working. However I'm writing this answer to give you a standardized alternative to "your sleep problem".

C++11 has introduced `sleep_for` & `sleep_until` which are defined in the namespace `std::this_thread`. When the former is for a span of time, the latter is for absolute time. I would give an example of `sleep_for` :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "start" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for (chrono::seconds(1));  // for C++14 users you can simply write 1s to denote 1 second
    cout << "end\n";   // will be printed after 1 second of printing 'start'
    return 0;
}
```

I'm giving you this answer because you should always prefer using features from the standard so as to make your program portable. You can differ from this advice only if it's really necessary.